# Need Restart OS Level After change virtual ip on keepalived

Tags: linux, high-availability, keepalived

I am  using keepalived for make HA current maxscale and using virtual IP on keepalived. If I change virtual IP on keepalived I must restart OS on VM or restart keepalived service only?

I am still confused about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No complete restart should be needed.

Restarting keepalived can be disruptive, but still it does not need full system reboot. For VRRP all IP are removed and added back. For IPVS  all rules are removed than added back. Reloading keepalived will only refresh what needs to be updated.

So try to use reload if possible.

Comment: hi thanks for update. thats mean,so if i change the virtual ip or add new virtual ip. only need reload  or restart keepalived service
correct ?

Comment: Yes. That should be enough.